# get multiple and single rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table

```
id = 1
name = 'one'
group = 1

id = 2
name = 'two'
group = 1

id = 3
name = 'three'
group = 2
```

and i have to get in one sql query all names which are singles, in this case id = 3
and another sql all names which are multiples, in this case id=1 and id=2, since they have the same group.
I suppose it should be a select in select but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use something similar to this:

```
select id
from yourtable
group by `group`
having count(`group`) = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ce31/7).

Then if you want to return all details, then you can expand the query to:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where id in (select id
            from yourtable t2
            group by `group`
            having count(`group`) = 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ce31/4).

If you want to return all rows that have the same group, then you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where `group` in (select `group`
                  from yourtable t2
                  group by `group`
                  having count(`group`) > 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff21/11)

Then if you want to return everything and a flag that identifies if it is a single or multiple, then you can use something similar to this. You will notice that I included a flag to show what `groups` have one row and then what groups have more than one row:

```
select *, 'single' Total
from yourtable t1
where `group` in (select `group`
                  from yourtable t2
                  group by `group`
                  having count(`group`) = 1)
union all
select *, 'multiple' Total
from yourtable t1
where `group` in (select `group`
                  from yourtable t2
                  group by `group`
                  having count(`group`) > 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff21/13)

Comment: Ok, its working but its getting only the singles , how to get the id 1 and 2 ? anyway thanks.

Comment: @Centurion . . . You change the `having` clause from ` = 1` to ` in (1, 2)`.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, the idea is to get ids which have group more than for two ids, i hope you understand